# How to add commas in value

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

i want to make money value have commas in it, i know this question is already ask, but i kinda new to javascript or jquery in general, my problem is i dont know how to apply some of those code with mine

- This is my jQuery code

```
<script>
$(function sum() {
    console.log($('.calc'))
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('.calc').each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    $("#subTotal").val(sum);
})();
  function calculateSubTotal() {
    var subtotal = $("#subTotal").val();
    $("#subTotalDiscount").val(subtotal - (Math.round(($("#inputDiscount").val() / 100) * subtotal)));
    var subtotal_discount = parseInt($("#subTotalDiscount").val());
    $("#subTotalTax").val(Math.round(($("#inputTax").val() / 100) * subtotal_discount));
    var subtotal_tax = parseInt($("#subTotalTax").val());
    var pph = $("#inputpph").val();
    $("#SubTotalpph").val(Math.round(parseInt($("#inputpph").val()*subtotal_discount)));
    var subtotal_pph = parseInt($("#SubTotalpph").val());
    var grandtotal = subtotal_discount + subtotal_tax + subtotal_pph;
    $("#grandTotal").val(grandtotal);
    }
</script>
```

- This is my table code

```
 <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-lg">
                        <div class="table-fix-head">
                            <table class="table table-fixed table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%;" id="tebal">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">DKM No </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Kode Produksi </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Kode Barang </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Deskripsi </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Jumlah/Quantity </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Unit </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Unit Price </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Sub Total </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php $i = 1;
                                    foreach ($query as $kiki) : ?>
                                        <tr class="table-row">
                                            <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $kiki["kodeprod"]; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $kiki["kodebarang_op"]; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $kiki["catatan"]; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $kiki["qty_op"]; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $kiki["unit_op"]; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $kiki["price"]; ?></td>
                                            <td class="calc"><?php echo $kiki["qty_op"]*$kiki["price"]; ?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <?php endforeach;?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

what i want is that the number in my table and my output value have commas like '122.000.000'

> the table preview : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdvDr.png

form :

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
               <label for="total" class="label-control" id="labelsubtotal">Total : </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9">
               <input type="number" value="" style="text-align: right;" class="form-control money" id="grandTotal" name="grandTotal" disabled>
          </div> 
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By modifying *t hj*'s answer, you could replace and also remove the commas for the purpose of calculating the prices :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log($('.calc'))
        var sum = 0.0;
        $('.calc').each(function () {
            sum += parseInt($(this).text());
        });
        $("#subTotal").val(addCommas(sum));
    });

    function calculateSubTotal() {
        var subtotal = removeCommas($("#subTotal").val());
        $("#subTotalDiscount").val(addCommas(+subtotal - (Math.round(($("#inputDiscount").val() / 100) * subtotal))));
        var subtotal_discount = parseInt(removeCommas($("#subTotalDiscount").val()));
        $("#subTotalTax").val(addCommas(Math.round(($("#inputTax").val() / 100) * subtotal_discount)));
        var subtotal_tax = parseInt(removeCommas($("#subTotalTax").val()));
        var pph = $("#inputpph").val();
        $("#SubTotalpph").val(addCommas(Math.round(parseInt(pph * subtotal_discount))));
        var subtotal_pph = parseInt(removeCommas($("#SubTotalpph").val()));
        var grandtotal = subtotal_discount + subtotal_tax + subtotal_pph;
        $("#grandTotal").val(grandtotal);
    }
    function addCommas(moneyValue) {
        return moneyValue.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
    }
    function removeCommas(moneyValue) {
        return moneyValue.toString().replace(".", "");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I've applying it to your codes, and modify some of your codes for better readability

Comment: im trying AutoNumeric but i still cant figure out how to use it

Comment: do i need to import plugin for regex first?

Comment: when i check console it said ```addCommas``` is not defined

Comment: what is function `sum()` do? when do you call it?

Comment: its sum up the value from table ```Sub Total``` and put it into input box with ```id = subTotal```

Comment: is the `sum()` function working, before you add the `addCommas` function?

Comment: I've updated my answer and put the `sum` codes inside the `$(document).ready()`

Comment: still no luck, sum still dissapear, is it possible to use autonumeric instead? i already tried autonumeric but it wont work

Comment: Could you update the current javascript and html codes on your question, the table and also the subtotal input so I could reproduce the issue? I'm afraid using autonumeric will have the same difficulty to implement

Comment: hey i just add the form codes and my js is using the one that you give and i give preview about my table

Comment: btw can you explain this `return moneyValue.toString().replace(".", "");` and `return moneyValue.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");`

Comment: I've tested your script, and it's not working. `return moneyValue.toString().replace(".", "");` is used to remove the `.` (the dot/comma) because if you want to calculate the tax/discount value it needs to be converted back as number without the comma.

Comment: this `return moneyValue.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");` is the regex pattern to replace each 3 digit with the comma

Comment: I've refactored the js code and make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vxbfa38/) of it if you're interested

Comment: thanks man can you explain how your code work? specially this one ```let subtotal = 0.0;
                $('.calc').each(function() {
                    subtotal += parseInt($(this).text());
                });```

Comment: `let subtotal = 0.0; $('.calc').each(function() { subtotal += parseInt($(this).text()); });` is used to sum each html element that having `calc` class then assign it to the `subtotal` variable

Comment: and do you know what this mean `/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."`

Comment: it's a regular expression pattern used by the javascript [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method to match the 3 digit, you could find more information about *regex* usage in this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or this [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) page

Answer (score 1):

By doing a javascript function

```
function commasNumber(yourMoneyValue) {
    return yourMoneyValue.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

or by using your example

```
   function commasNumber() {
        var subtotal = $("#subTotal").val();
        var valueWithCommas = subtotal.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        $("#subTotal").val(valueWithCommas);
 }
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of what your regex if finding, particularly the lookaheads? (I can't quite parse it, and I may not be the only one.)

Comment: hi can you explain `/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","`

Comment: you can try at regex tester

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript like @t-hj post or if you want to use PHP, here's some example

```
<?php echo number_format($kiki["price"], 0, '', ',') ?>
```

Read more about [PHP number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)